# RegExp match a word NOT spelled with the case specified (like \bOK\b but would only match oK, Ok or ok)

Tags: regex, pcre

I would need to match words/abbreviations that are NOT written in the "standard" way, whatever it might be.

Should work similarly than `\bOK\b` to match in this manner:

```
Match here -> Ok
Match here -> oK
Match here -> ok
Would not match here -> OK
```

I have lot of words that should be checked this way and if it is longer than couple character adding check for all permutations of different cases are very large large, very quick.

So looking for more elegant solution instead of something making regexps for all permutations or common wrong casing like this:

```
(?-i)\bSaas\b
(?-i)\bsAAS\b
(?-i)\bSAAS\b
...
```

Instead of just matching a word with case different that "SaaS" that I would like to find (kind of misspelled) non standard case

Answer (score 4):

Since PCRE is supported, you can use the regular expression

```
\b(?!OK)(?i)OK\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jMOmHi/1)

This works because `(?i)` does not takes effect until the negative lookahead has been executed (something I was unaware of until I tried it).

---

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
\b      match a word boundary
(?!OK)  a negative lookahead asserts that the next two characters not 'OK'
(?i)    match the remainder of the pattern with the case-indifferent flag set 
OK      match the literal 'OK', 'ok', 'Ok' or 'oK'
\b      match a word boundary
```

---

Similarly, you could write

```
\b(?!SaaS)(?i)saas\b
```

which of course could instead be written

```
\b(?!SaaS)(?i)SaaS\b
```

or

```
\b(?!SaaS)(?i)sAAs\b
```

and so on.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wddvGh/1)

Comment: `(?i)` can also be applied locally: `(?i:OK)`. `\b` is not affected by it, of course, but this may save a future maintainer if they were to add something at the end of the regex and can't figure out why that match case-insensitively. Just like with global variables, modifier changes should have their scopes limited if not placed at the very start.

Comment: @InSync, good point (something else I didn't know). I see that one can also write `(?-i)` to turn off case-indifference in-line.

Comment: A variant: https://regex101.com/r/jMOmHi/2

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, Nice one.

Comment: Thank you all very much. 

This made my app much faster, because of it will not have to handle tons of false positives.

Elapsed time 23,4539s
Total rule runs 1 272 327 on 3 023 files

When I handled case-difference in code and got those false positives it was about 3-4x slower.

Comment: I am very pleased to hear that you found this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that regex alone is useful to solve. You should just do a second check to see whether it matches the thing you don't want.

```
// pseudocode
let pattern = "(SaaS)"

let match = regex.match(pattern, str, caseSensitive=false)

if (match && match.group(1) != "SaaS") {
    // the pattern matched a different way of spelling
}
```

Comment: OK, I was hoping there would have been some way directly in the RegExp, but surely can do something like that you suggested.